# Ruby hash/sub-hash existance check

Tags: ruby, exception, hash

I find myself needing to put guards like this:

```
if hash[:foo] && hash[:foo][:bar] && hash[:foo][:bar][:baz] 
    puts hash[:foo][:bar][:baz]
end
```

I'd like to shorten this in some way; I know I can wrap in a begin/rescue block but that seems worse. Maybe something like:
[ruby Hash include another hash, deep check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826969/ruby-hash-include-another-hash-deep-check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
def follow_hash(hash, path)
  path.inject(hash) { |accum, el| accum && accum[el] }
end

value = follow_hash(hash, [:foo, :bar, :baz])
puts value if value
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this article very informative: http://avdi.org/devblog/2011/06/28/do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try/

```
value = Maybe(params)[:foo][:bar][:baz][:buz]
```